# Smooth functions on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, partial-differential-equations

Let $K:=\overline{U}$ be the closure of $U$ open bounded connected set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. A definition of $C^k(U)$ is (Evans, Partial differential equations, p. 618):
$$S_1=\{u \in C^k(U), \partial_\alpha u  \text{ uniformly continuous on }U, 0\leq |\alpha|\leq k\}$$

Clearly, $S_2=\{ u \in C^k(U) \text{ such that }u=v|_K, v\in C^k(V), V\supseteq K \text{ open}\}$ contains $S_1$. Under which hypothesis is $S_1=S_2$?

Looking around, the notion of quasiconvexity of $U$ is sufficient, in the case $k=1$, cfr. [theorem 5.1](https://orbi.uliege.be/bitstream/2268/252060/1/Frerick_et_al-2020-Results_in_Mathematics.pdf). For quasiconvexity, being a bounded Lipschitz domain is enough.

How about the case $k\leq \infty$ arbitrary? Which conditions should $U$ satisfy? Is e.g. being $U$ a bounded Lipschitz domain sufficient?

Comment: I guess you want $V \supset K$ open? Otherwise you could just take $V=U$ and the statement $S_1 \supset S_2$ would not be true (you claim the converse, which I don't think holds in general).

Comment: @PhoemueX That's correct, let me edit the question, thanks.

Comment: In $S_1$ you consider functions with $U$ as a domain, in $S_2$ with $K$.

Comment: @Mateo True, I wrote the question too quickly. Now it should be fine.

Comment: In $S_1$ you make assumptions only on the first derivatives $\partial_i u$?

Comment: You might want to search for "stein extension operator". This should show that Lipschitz donations are fine.